# Back button should quit directly

Tags: android

i have two main Activity with two separate XML file that design  for  two languages.
when someone tap on Image button on Main Activity ENG ,it will change and another activity with different layout and language shows up.

the point is, i have on Back Pressed() method that if user pressed back button twice , it should exit the app.

now what i get is when tap a lot and switch between two activity the back pressed button wants to back to previous activity to the end that it seems absolutely right but i need to quit directly. what can i do?

```
public void onBackPressed() 
{

   if(count == 1)
   {
      count=0;
      finish();
   }
   else
   {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Press Back again to quit.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      count++;
      super.onBackPressed();
   }
   return;
}
```

thanx

Comment: unless the behavior of your activities is really different between the 2 language, it is unlikely that you need 2 activities, 2 layouts should be sufficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple scenario, You start Your Activity B from Activity A by button press:

```
    yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

      @Override
       public void onClick(View v){

       Intent i = new Intent(YourActivity.this,YourNextActivity.class);
       startActivity(i);
       finish();//finish Your first activity


    }


  });
```

The only thing You have to do is, to finish the first Activity from where You get to the next one. Then Activity B has no chance to go back to Activity A and the app "finishs".

Answer (score 0):

This is an article about exit and quit in android apps.
http://android.nextapp.com/site/fx/doc/exit

but for your app purposes you code use these lines:

```
finish();          
moveTaskToBack(true);   
System.exit(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct behaviour, to *quit*, you'd have to call `finish()` on both activities. However, if you create the second Activity with the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flag, you'll be able to quit as described. However, your users won't be able to go back in the activity hierarchy - are you sure you want that?

Anyways, this way you'll be able to quit:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```